# `cat()` inside `if()` statement produces unwanted behaviour

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

Using the following example rmarkdown

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: pdf_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
```


## R Markdown

```{r}
summary(cars)

cat("banaaaaaaa")

cat("banaaaaaaa")

cat("banaaaaaaa")

```

```{r}
if(1 == 0){
print("this will not print")
}else{
summary(cars)

cat("banaaaaaaa")

cat("banaaaaaaa")

cat("banaaaaaaa")
}
```
````

produces the pdf below

[image]

How can I get the code in the second chunk inside the `if` to produce the same results as the code chunk above it?

Comment: Couldn't you just add `print` around the summary ?

Comment: @erocoar yes but that doesn't fix the `cat` part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the `print` commmand. With cat command, you need to manually specify the new line (`\n`) command. Try this:

```
if(1 == 0){

    print("this will not print")

} else {
    print(summary(cars))
    cat("banaaaaaaa")
    cat('\n') # just copy paste this
    cat("banaaaaaaa")
    cat('\n')
    cat("banaaaaaaa")
}

     speed           dist       
 Min.   : 4.0   Min.   :  2.00  
 1st Qu.:12.0   1st Qu.: 26.00  
 Median :15.0   Median : 36.00  
 Mean   :15.4   Mean   : 42.98  
 3rd Qu.:19.0   3rd Qu.: 56.00  
 Max.   :25.0   Max.   :120.00  
banaaaaaaa 
banaaaaaaa 
banaaaaaaa
```

Comment: Or just `cat("banaaaaaaa\n")`, no need for the comma.

Comment: @ManishSaraswat so i also have to add `cat(\n)` between every `cat("banaaaaaaa\n")` to get the newline gap between them. This also means i get `##` in between each line of `banaaaaaaa`.

Comment: Do you also want `###` between each 'bananaaa' ?

Comment: I would prefer not to but that is not as bad as having to write `cat(\n)` between each line :/

Comment: yeah, workable thx, but a bit of a nightmare, would be interested in knowing how why this happens and could be solved otherwise.